# Как вывести в div информацию полученную из json ajax заспроса

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, xmlparser, скрипт

Подскажите, пожалуйста, не могу разобраться в остальных примерах. Есть div на сайте, куда выводятся комментарии, по 5 штук за раз. Ниже есть кнопка "Загрузить еще". При нажатии на нее отправляется ajax запрос на файл обработчик, который делат запрос в mysql и получает результаты с него. Эти результаты проходят цикл и формируются в json.

```
$rowCom = array();  
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $rowCom[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rowCom);
```

В js файле я принимаю их:

```
success:(function(data){

            data = JSON.parse(data);
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $.each(data, function(index, data){
                    //тут должны они выводиться
                });
                inProgress = false;
                startFrom += 10;
            }
        })
```

Как сделать так, чтобы они выводились в нужном div? Учитывая, что эта полученная информация также является div с множеством условий и переменных? Например, учитываетяс в каком блоке выводится информация, зарегистрирован ли пользователь, кнопки принадлежащие только этому блоку, сравнения дат. Через append это сделать будет очень накладно.

Пример childDiv

```
<div class="comment">
<h4 class="<?php
    if ($rowCom['comDateNow'] == $today) {
        echo 'today';
    }?>"><?php
    if ($rowCom['comDateNow'] == $today) {
        echo 'Сегодня';
    }
    else {echo $rowCom['comDateNow']; } 
?></h4>
<h5>Оценка: <span><?php echo $rowCom['rate'];?></span></h5>
<h6><?php echo $rowCom['firstComTitle'];?></h6>
<p><?php echo $rowCom['firstCom'];?></p>
<h6>Клиент</h6>
<p><?php echo $rowCom['comUser'];?></p>
<h6>Телефон для связи</h6>
<p><?php echo $rowCom['comUsertel'];?></p>
<div class="commentAction">
    <h6>Переместить в</h6>
    <div class="actBtn">
        <?php
            $thatId = $rowCom['id'];
            if($thatStatus == 1) {
                echo "<input type='button' class='move' data-user='$user' data-id='$thatId' data-status='GotToPos' id='pos' name='pos' value='P'>";

            }

        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#parentDiv').append(data);` - добавит данные `data` в конец блока с идентификатором `parentDiv`

Comment: не помогает, не грузит ничего, хотя информация доходит

Comment: То есть, `console.log(data);` показывает html код нужный? Если да то ещё так можно `$('#parentDiv').html(data);` - так содержимое блока parentDiv заменяется данными с data

Comment: console.log(data); показывает объект: {id: "7", firstComTitle: "Опрос", firstCom: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…elit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.", secComTitle: "Что. где и почему?", secCom: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…elit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.", …}

Comment: `//тут должны они выводиться` - вот в этом месте?

Comment: я имел ввиду, что прописать в том месте, чтобы выводилось в div

Comment: аа... Ну, тут смотря какая структура, или смотря как вы хотите выводить. Вот вам пример `$('#parentDiv').append('<p>'+data.firstComTitle+'</p><p>'+data.firstCom+'</p>');`

Comment: Так этой конструкции я и хочу избежать, так как в childDiv выводится инфа с условиями: скажем по дате: если дата совпадает с сегодняшней, то выводится слово "Сегодня", но это самое просто условие. Также там присутствуют кнопки, которые нужны только для этого childDiv и некоторые другие условия, которые определяются с сервера.

Comment: добавил пример childDiv в описание проблемы вначале